# How to add a startup program via terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Is there a command in bash to add another command into the list of startup applications in Ubuntu? Any ideas?

Comment: /etc/rc.local file add any command, it will by execute on system startup. Check this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/598195/how-to-add-a-script-to-startup-applications-from-the-command-line

Comment: I need to do it automatically via a bash command. You mean I should append the file with the command I need?

Comment: First check that link, there is a lot of ideas how to do it, and yes It would work with append.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need!